# saving data from clone form php

Tags: php

[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58GW8.png) i have a form, where user and more requirement. but while saving only the first input value is being saved.the requirementID, requirement and requirementType are the data that should be saved more than 1 time, but it is not.

```
// Values to insert
                    $requirementID=0;
                    $functionName=$_POST ["functionName"];
                    $requirement = $_POST["requirement"];
                    $requirementType = $_POST["requirementType"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO requirements (requirementID,requirement,       functionID,requirementTypeID) VALUES 
                        ('$requirementID', '$requirement','$functionName',' $requirementType')";
$result = mysql_query( $sql,$conn );
 }
```

Comment: you can store that values in session and use this as many time. Follw this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: i want to save the data,please look at the form maybe you would be able to help me by understand the form, the functionName will be save for each input but the rest will change as each input has different date